# Remember Background Color/Colour With Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, background-color, color-picker

i have been looking all over the internet and cant seem to find an article that is relevant to my needs.
I have never worked with cookies before but i thought this might be a simple task...
Turns out i was quite wrong :/

Basically i have a colour picker and i would like for the browser to remember the colour set each time it is set so that when they come back to the site the background colour is the same as when they left.

I am using this colour picker http://lindekleiv.bitbucket.org/colorpicker/

With this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorpicker').colorPicker({
    colorChange: function(e, ui) {
    $('body').css({backgroundColor: ui.color})
    }
    });

    $('#colorpicker').colorPicker('setColor', 0, 0, 6, 1);
})
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this very simple cookie handling object I wrote:

```
var Cookie = {
    set: function(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        } else { var expires = ""; }

        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + location.pathname;
    },

    unset: function(name) { Cookie.set(name, "", -1); },

    get: function(name) {
        var search = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]*);");
        var result = search.exec(document.cookie);
        return result ? result[1] : undefined;
    }
};
```

So your code would become:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorpicker').colorPicker({
        colorChange: function(e, ui) {
            $('body').css({backgroundColor: ui.color});
            Cookie.set('bgc', $('body').css('background-color'), 365);
        }
    });

    $('#colorpicker').colorPicker('setColor', 0, 0, 6, 1);

    if (Cookie.get('bgc')) {
        $('body').css({ backgroundColor: Cookie.get('bgc') });
    }
});
```

Comment: I implemented my Cookie function into your code in my answer above.
Looking at your code in the comments, it seems like you execute `Cookie.set('bgr', ...)` right after a `return` statement. Please provide a full example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is pretty simple. You can just set the cookie for the background color using this:

```
document.cookie = "color=" + color;
```

And recall a cookie that was saved using this:

```
var color = loadCookies();

function loadCookies(){
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                    '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                    "color" +
                    '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
}
```